# How to grab values between xml in SQl statement

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, ibm-sterling

When I run a SQL against one of the tables, this is the value i get against column instruction

```
<GiftMessage>
  <Properties>
    <Property Type="FONT">50</Property>
    <Property Type="SCRIPT">512</Property>
    <Property Type="CARD">B</Property>
    <Property Type="FORMATOPTION">N</Property>
    <Property Type="WRTIE">D</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Line SeqNo="1"><![CDATA[]]></Line>
  <Line SeqNo="2"><![CDATA[]]></Line>
  <Line SeqNo="3"><![CDATA[]]></Line>
  <Line SeqNo="4"><![CDATA[            ***712020line2***]]></Line>
</GiftMessage>
```

How do i grab the value "712020line2" alone from the column to show in my output query using select statement.

Apologize for late reply,
I am connected to Oracle database using Oracle sql developer, and below is the query we run.

select instruction_text,order_no from INSTRUCTION_DETAIL where instruction_text like '%712020%';

**Purpose**
We used to place around 50-70 orders and share it with different team for shipment, updating each order on what needs to be done is tedious task, so we are planning to update that instruction with "what action the shipment team needs to do", so at the end of
day, we just run this query and download it to excel and share. But the thing is the instruction_text column value comes out in an xml format, so looking for a way to fetch only the instruction text, like in above case, '712020line2', from that xml

Comment: Can you show what have you tried in SQL. Mention the specific issue instead of asking SO to solve the problem

Comment: What is your database? Each database vendor has its own SQL dialect and way of XML handling.

Comment: Hi Yitzhak and Narenda, I have updated the details. When you guys get time, could you please help me out.